# How to check if front matter empty or not in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Let's just say I have a source of content that comes from markdown and yaml with front matter that sometimes has empty value. For example:

```yaml
# front matter
title: Foo
subtitle:
```

```js
// foo.js
import React from 'react';

const Foo = ({data}) => {
    return(
       // check if {data.subtitle} not empty 
       // <p>{data.subtitle}/p>
       // else
       // ...
    )
}

export default Foo;
```

I wonder what is the best way to to check the value of the front matter. Is it through conditional statements (if else) in the jsx template?

The main goal is that Gatsby only renders some elements if the value of a particular front matter is not empty

Comment: How else would you do it *besides* an `if` statement (or ternary, etc)? I might not put all the logic in the render, rather pull it out or componentize it, but ultimately it's the same thing: if there's something to render, render it, if not, don't.

Comment: to be honest i am still confused because i don't really know react and gatsby well.
if you dont mind can you elaborate more clearly in an example

Comment: Just look up "react conditional rendering".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common patterns for conditional rendering in JSX:

1. If you only want to render if true (or if not true), use `&&`:

   ```
   {data.subtitle && <p>{data.subtitle}</p>}
   // or
   {!renderDisabled && <p>Something</p>}
   ```

   Note that in the second case you're not using `||`; this is because if the left hand side of the statement is truthy it will be returned and rendered, and you probably don't intend to output something like `<div>true</div>`.
2. If you want to render one of two different branches depending on the condition, use a ternary:

   ```
   {data.subtitle ? <p>{data.subtitle}</p> : <p>Default subtitle</p>}
   ```

Comment: Last night I tried a similar step, `{data.hero.subtitle !== null && <span>show something</span>}` what do you think? both mine and yours runs perfectly but it looks like I'm facing another problem, because [I can't make a query if the filed is null](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/6800) do you have any reference to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is stylistic but the most terse way would be a ternary

```
return data.subtitle? <p>{data.subtitle}</p>:<>Whatever else </>
```